# Blackberry - Clickable ListView With Different ID's

Tags: blackberry

I facing some issues in listview on navigation click. When i add `add(myListView);` inside for loop, this loop add records on screen again and again for example 1st time add 1st record, 2nd time add 1st record again with 2nd record. Below is the code:

```java
for(int i=0;  i < totalfriends; i++){
    imagearr = object.getJSONArray("pic_user_pro");
    imgname = imagearr.getString(i);

    if (imgname == "" || imgname == "null")
    {
        listThumb = getImage.getImageFromUrl("http://ugo.offroadstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/null.png"+connParams+"");
        bmpResized = GPATools.ResizeTransparentBitmap(listThumb, 80, 80,
        Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);
    }
    else
    {
        listThumb = getImage.getImageFromUrl("http://ugo.offroadstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/"+imgname+""+connParams+"");
        bmpResized = GPATools.ResizeTransparentBitmap(listThumb, 80, 80,
        Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);
    }
    listTitlearr = object.getJSONArray("nick_name");
    listTitle = listTitlearr.getString(i);
    friendidarr = object.getJSONArray("friends_user_id");
    friendid = friendidarr.getString(i);
    listDescarr = object.getJSONArray("interest");
    listDesc = listDescarr.getString(i);
    listDesc2arr = object.getJSONArray("location");
    listDesc2 = listDesc2arr.getString(i);

    v.addElement(new ListRander(bmpResized,listTitle ,listDesc,listDesc2, navBar));
    // CustomListField With Event
    final String nextGiftsId = friendid;
    myListView = new CustomListField(v){
        public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time)
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ViewMoreHotlist(nextGiftsId));
            return true;
        }
    };
    add(myListView);
}// For Loop End
```

And also if i add `ListView` outside the for loop and i add `add(myListView);` outside for loop, this loop adds records on screen correctly but get ID of last record every time if i click on 1st record.

I want all record display on screen correct and when i click on any record it takes id of that record not other record.

Comment: this extends list field ?

Comment: @Signare .. Yes, this extends from ListField.

Comment: how many **lists** do you want?  do you want **one** list, or **many** lists?  one list can have many rows.

Comment: @Nate .. i want many list. Basically it depends on counts `totalfriends`, that get value from database & add list-field on screen according to that value.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want many **rows**?  One row for each friend?

Comment: @Nate ... Please check this image [link]http://omaghconcepts.com/Friends.png , At that time this shows only one record , when data increase , list field rows also increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to add more than one **List**.  You want **one** list with many **rows**.  Each record in your JSON data should be one row in the list.

So, you should keep this code

```java
myListView = new CustomListField(v){
    public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time)
    {
        /* UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ViewMoreHotlist(nextGiftsId)); */
        return true;
    }
};
add(myListView);
```

**outside** of the `for` loop.  You should just be adding **rows** inside the `for` loop.  You are doing this inside the loop:

```java
v.addElement(new ListRander(bmpResized,listTitle ,listDesc,listDesc2, navBar));
```

which looks ok.  I can't see how you define and later use `v`, but the list will need to get its data from `v` somehow.  It sounds like you've already done that, based on this comment:

> if i add ListView outside the for loop and i add add(myListView); outside for loop, this loop adds records on screen correctly

So, your only problem now is that when you detect a list click, you're getting the ID of the last row.  You'll need to change your click handler to something like this:

```java
myListView = new CustomListField(v){
    public boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time)
    {
        // which row is selected?
        int index = getSelectedIndex();
        String friendId = object.getJSONArray("friends_user_id").getString(index);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ViewMoreHotlist(friendId));
        return true;
    }
};
```

you will need to make sure that you keep the JSON response `object` available for when `trackwheelClick()` is called.  You could make it a member variable in your class ... maybe you've already done this.

The key to solve your problem is getting the selected index after the click with `getSelectedIndex()`.